# Give a counterexample, if possible, to these universally quantified statements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Give a counterexample, if possible, to these universally quantified statements, where the domain for all variables consists of all integers. That is, show a reason why the statement is NOT universally true when applied to the domain of integers.
a. $\forall x (|x| > 0)$
b. $\forall x \exists y (x = 1/y) $
c. For each of the quantified statements in a-b above, give a domain for the variables for which each universally quantified statement a-b is true.

For part a I put $x=0$. For b. I'm not sure what it is asking. I put $y=0$ as a shot in the dark but I've no clue.

Comment: $y$ isn't the one you can pick. It's $x$. But $0$ is correct.

Comment: So for where it is true in C. I could just use x = 1?

Comment: $x=1$ is not a domain. You could use $\{1\}$. That's not the one that's intended, but it works.

Comment: So like x > or equal to 1?

Comment: That is a description of another possible domain. But the actual domain is $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}|x\geq 1\}$. It's a set.

Comment: Take the empty set  $\phi $ for the domain.For any clause $ S$ the contradiction of  the sentence $\forall  x \in  \phi (S)$ is equivalent to  $\exists x \in \phi (\text {not }  S).$

Answer (score 1):

a. Let $x=0$. Then $|x|=0\not> 0$.

b. Let $x=2$. Then there does not exist a $y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $x=\frac{1}{y}$.

c. The first statement is satisfied $\forall x\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ since $\forall x\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}, |x| > 0.$ The second statement is only satisfied $\forall x\in\{-1,1\}$ because $1=\frac{1}{1}$ and $-1=\frac{1}{-1}$ (observe that the domain of $x$ would be $x\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ if we allowed $y\in\mathbb R$).

Therefore, the domain for the first statement is $x\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and the domain for the second statement is $x\in\{-1,1\}$

Answer (score 0):

Part $b$ is saying that every number has a reciprocal. Not so! $0$ doesn't, so you need to define your domain to exclude $0$.